# Are F3 visas going to be affected by the new presidential proclamation (June 22, 2020)?

Tags: united-states, immigration

I called NVC and they told me that only certain types of visas are going to be affected. I have read the [presidential proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspending-entry-aliens-present-risk-u-s-labor-market-following-coronavirus-outbreak/) but it is still not clear for me if everyone is going to be affected by this proclamation or not as I only see this:

> (a)  an H-1B or H-2B visa, and any alien accompanying or following to
> join such alien;
>
> (b)  a J visa, to the extent the alien is participating in an intern,
> trainee, teacher, camp counselor, au pair, or summer work travel
> program, and any alien accompanying or following to join such alien;
> and
>
> (c)  an L visa, and any alien accompanying or following to join such
> alien.

Sorry for the question, I was supposed to migrate this year. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

The proclamation §2 says "The entry into the United States of any alien seeking entry pursuant to any of the following nonimmigrant visas is hereby suspended and limited, subject to section 3 of this proclamation", but F3 is classed exclusively as an [immigrant visa.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/all-visa-categories.html)

Comment: You might better say that there's no F-3 nonimmigrant category, because the category designations overlap.  For example, if someone tells you they have an F-1 or F-2 visa, you woudn't know whether they have an immigrant visa or a nonimmigrant visa.

Comment: Sorry for ignorance, I am really confused. So, as F3 is classified as an immigrant visa that means that they are not going to be suspended this year? Thanks for your kind response.

Comment: @math4everyone unfortunately for you, one of the other things this proclamation does is to extend the [proclamation of April 22](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspending-entry-immigrants-present-risk-u-s-labor-market-economic-recovery-following-covid-19-outbreak/), which prohibited most new immigrants from entering the US.